# Python Function: using a batch file to pass parameters from .txt file to python function and execute function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, batch-file, parameters

I would like to pass 1 or more parameters from a text file to a python function using a batch file. Is this possible? Ideally I would like to read from a line in the text file which would pass the specific com port to the python function, my_function and these actions could be done using a batch file

I can currently call a python script using a batch file as shown below. Separately I can also call a python function and pass a parameter to it using Python Shell. I need to be able to pass different values from a text file to the same function which is where I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Current batch file code calling a python script

```
echo[
@echo. The Step below calls the script which opens COM 12
echo[

"C:\Python\python.exe" "C:\Scripts\open_COM12.py"
```

Current python code to pass parameter (com port number) and call python function

```
import ConfigComPort as cw
from ConfigComPort import my_function
my_function('12')
```

Connection successfully made

Text File contents

```
COM_PORTS
12
19
23
22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file called `parameters.txt` with data

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

And a function

```py
def my_function(some_text):
    print("I was called with " + some_text)
```

Then you can do this to pass every line of the file to the function:

```py
with open('parameters.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        # remove the # and space from the next line to enable output to console:
        # print(line.rstrip())

        my_function(line.rstrip())
```

Note that the `rstrip()` method in all my examples strips off the trailing newline (as well as other trailing whitespace) that would otherwise be part of each line.

If your parameter file has a header, as in your example, you have multiple possibilities to skip that.

For example you can read all lines at once into a list and then iterate over a subset:

```py
with open('parameters.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    all_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in my_file.readlines()]

# print(all_lines)

for line in all_lines[1:]:
    # print(line)

    my_function(line)
```

However, that would just ignore the header. If you accidentally passed a wrong file or one that has invalid content, this could spell trouble.

It's better to check whether the header of the file is correct. You can just expand the code from above:

```py
with open('parameters.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    all_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in my_file.readlines()]

# print(all_lines)

if all_lines[0] != 'COM_PORTS':
    raise RuntimeError("file has wrong header")

for line in all_lines[1:]:
    # print(line)

    my_function(line)
```

Or you can do this inside the loop, for instance:

```py
expect_header = True

with open('parameters.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        stripped = line.rstrip()
        if expect_header:
            if stripped != 'COM_PORTS':
                raise RuntimeError("header of file is wrong")

            expect_header = False
            continue

        # print(stripped)

        my_function(stripped)
```

Or you can use an generator expression to check the header outside of the loop:

```py
with open('parameters.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    all_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in my_file.readlines())

if next(all_lines) != 'COM_PORTS':
    raise RuntimeError("file has wrong header")

for line in all_lines:
    # print(line)

    my_function(line)
```

I would likely prefer this last one, as it is has a clear structure and no magic numbers (such as `0` and `1`, referring to which line is the header and how many to skip, respectively) and it doesn't need to read all lines into memory at once.

However, the solution further above that reads all lines into a list at once is probably better if you want to do further processing on them as the data is already available in that case and you don't need to read the file again.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have a few questions regarding the first few code snippets. I assume the code knows to look in the default location for the parameters.txt file? My location is C:\Python. Also, how can I confirm that the function has read the contents of the parameter file?

Comment: If you don't give an explicit directory where to access a file, it will look in the so-called "current directory" or "working directory". This can be anywhere. On a command line you can do `C:` and then `cd \some\place` to change the current drive and directory. Then this is where the script would fetch the file from. If instead you start it via clicking on a Shortcut (i.e. Icon on the Desktop or Start Menu), you can change the working directory in the Shortcut properties. Of course you can also change my example to include the full path to your file. `open('C:\\some\\where\\file.txt', 'r')`

Comment: With confirm you mean you want to print the lines for debugging? This won't work without disruption in all of the examples. The only ones where this is OK are the two that read all the lines into a list. You can just do `print(all_lines)` there. The first and the last 2 examples don't easily work like that, as they consume the lines of the file "on the go". Whichever consumes them first gets them and whichever comes after gets none. In those cases you would have to either read the files again or use `itertools.tee()` to be able to consume them twice.

Comment: However, in all examples you can also print out each line as it is about to be processed alongside the function call. Just add a `print(line)` or `print(stripped)` above the `my_function(foo)` call, as appropriate.

Comment: I added some comments to the code to show you where you could add debugging `print()`s.